# Django: Can't login with Allauth

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-urls, django-allauth

I tried all login, signup process with usign ***allauth*** in Django.
But I have this problem:

```
File "C:\Users\Mircal\Desktop\Project\core\urls.py", line 22, in <module> 
path('accounts/login/', name='account_login'),  
TypeError: _path() missing 1 required positional argument: 'view'
```

core/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('accounts/login/', name='account_login'),
]
```

I have got *apps/accounts/login.py* and *templates/accounts/login.html*

I setup this using https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html

What can I do for solution?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you don't need the third line `path('accounts/login/', name='account_login'),` because it is included inside `allauth.urls`

Moreover, there is a mistake in that line because it misses the view argument before your name argument.

Comment: Actually you are right for login. But we need allauth for otherside. My manager wants using this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you've encountered a common issue when setting up `django-allauth`. The error you're seeing is due to an incorrect usage of the `path()` function in your `urls.py`. The `path()` function expects at least two arguments: a route and a view, but in your case, you've only provided the route and a `name` argument, which is causing the `TypeError`.

Here's how you can fix this issue:

1. **Correct the URL Pattern:**

   - The `django-allauth` library already includes a URL pattern for login, so you don't need to define it again in your `urls.py`.
   - You should remove the line `path('accounts/login/', name='account_login')` from your `urls.py`.
2. **Updated `core/urls.py`:**

   ```py
   from django.contrib import admin
   from django.urls import include, path

   urlpatterns = [
       path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
       path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
       # Remove or comment out the following line
       # path('accounts/login/', name='account_login'),
   ]
   ```
3. **Ensure Templates are Correctly Set Up:**

   - Make sure your `templates/accounts/login.html` is correctly set up and is in a directory that Django can find. By default, Django will look for templates in each app's `templates` directory and any directories specified in the `TEMPLATES` setting in your `settings.py`.
4. **Follow the Official Documentation:**

   - Since you're following the [django-allauth documentation](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html), ensure that all installation steps are correctly implemented, including adding `'allauth'`, `'allauth.account'`, and `'allauth.socialaccount'` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` and configuring the necessary context processors.

After making these changes, your login functionality should work as expected. If the problem persists, it might be worth checking if there are any issues with your template or the allauth configurations in your `settings.py`.

Answer (score -1):

You should add a view for your path('accounts/login/', name='account_login') and place it in front of path('admin/', admin.site.urls)